# Merge multiple pandas columns into new column

Tags: python, pandas, analysis

I have a dataframe where some of the columns indicate whether or not a set of survey questions was seen. For example:

```
Q1_Seen    Q2_Seen    Q3_Seen    Q4_Seen
    Q1a        nan        nan        nan
    nan        Q2a        nan        nan
    nan        nan        Q3d        nan
    nan        Q2c        nan        nan
```

I would like to collapse these columns into one column, let's say `Q_Seen`, that would take on the form:

```
Q_Seen
   Q1a
   Q2a
   Q3d
   Q2c
```

Note that each row would be mutually exclusive: if there is a value in one of the columns, all the others would be NaN.

I tried doing this with `pd.concat`, but it didn't seem to be producing correct results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Q_Seen'] = df.stack().values

>>> df

Q1_Seen    Q2_Seen    Q3_Seen     Q4_Seen     Q_Seen
    Q1a        nan        nan         nan        Q1a
    nan        Q2a        nan         nan        Q2a
    nan        nan        Q3d         nan        Q3d
    nan        Q2c        nan         nan        Q2c
```

Answer (score 4):

Using column-wise `max()` -- i.e. `max(axis=1)` -- would allow you to collapse all values into a single column:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Q1_Seen": ['Q1a', None, None, None], "Q2_Seen": [None, "Q2a", None, "Q2c"], "Q3_Seen": [None, None, "Q3d", None],"Q4_Seen": [None, None, None, None]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
  Q1_Seen Q2_Seen Q3_Seen Q4_Seen
0     Q1a    None    None    None
1    None     Q2a    None    None
2    None    None     Q3d    None
3    None     Q2c    None    None

In [4]: df['Q_Seen'] = df.max(axis=1)

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
  Q1_Seen Q2_Seen Q3_Seen Q4_Seen Q_Seen
0     Q1a    None    None    None    Q1a
1    None     Q2a    None    None    Q2a
2    None    None     Q3d    None    Q3d
3    None     Q2c    None    None    Q2c
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q1': [1, None, None], 'Q2': [None, 2, None], 'Q3': [None, None, 3]})
df['Q'] = df.concat([df['Q1'], df['Q2'], df['Q3']]).dropna()
```

There could be a more elegant solution, but this is what first popped into my head.